# Multiply several elements inside the cost function using CPLEX

Tags: java, cplex

I'am using CPLEX in java and I want to add into the cost function the following multiplication:

```
Minimize(A*B*X)

where:
A ∈ ℝ^1*n
B ∈ ℝ^m*n
X ∈ ℝ^n*1
```

As far as I know, `A*B` would be something like:

```
for(int i = 0; i < m; i++)
  for(int j = 0; j < n; j++)
    objective.addTerm(A[i], B[i][j]);
```

But how can I multiply these three terms (`A*B*X`)? I did not found much information on this topic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you want to formulate a model that is not supported by CPLEX (e.g., it is not linear nor quadratic). Is that right? If not please give more details. See [here](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSA5P_12.9.0/ilog.odms.cplex.help/CPLEX/UsrMan/topics/preface/whatdoes.html) for an explanation of the types of models that CPLEX can solve.

Your example for `A*B` looks more or less correct (depending on the type of `objective`), but I think you are likely missing the first argument specifying the coefficient. For example, see [IloLQNumExpr.addTerm](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSA5P_12.9.0/ilog.odms.cplex.help/refjavacplex/html/ilog/concert/IloLQNumExpr.html#addTerm(double,%20ilog.concert.IloNumVar,%20ilog.concert.IloNumVar)).

If you haven't already, you should take a look at the java examples that are included with CPLEX (e.g., QPex1.java, SocpEx1.java, etc.).